# ubuntu 22.04 files gui fails randomly in drag and drop copying to external HD

Tags: nautilus, copy

I often copy multiple files at once from directories on my internal HD to several external HDs, and since the file names are heterogeneous, I generally just use the files gui with drag and drop rather than the command line.  I didn't notice at first, but after I upgraded to 'jammy jellyfish' or whatever the new version is called, some of the files are not actually getting copied.  Instead, empty files with the correct names but no content are generated.  Sometimes every file will copy correctly, but about every 3rd or 4th time I copy a batch over, one or two files out of the one or two score files I'm copying will have such a problem, and I have to copy those files again and overwrite the empty files.

I've done my various apt-gets and whatnot, so all of my system files should be up to date, and I haven't seen any system complaints about corrupt files related to copying. (Jellyfish did not like my 'crossover' package, and I had to go in and f**k around to remove it manually from the packages, but it's a wine thing, and should have nothing to do with nautilus or file copying per se.)

Is anyone else having this sort of problem?

(edit: and, of course, is there a fix for this behaviour.)

Comment: No, but as it sounds, it could be a hardware issue, e.g., with the connection cable, where perhaps there are random small bad electrical contacts.

Comment: vanadium - hmm.  That is a thought.  I've only noticed it so far on one of the two external drives I've got connected, mainly because I haven't moved anything to the other one since the upgrade.  I'll check to see if I have the same problem show up on the other external drive, since it's using a different physical connector.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exactly same problem with copy files.
Few days ago I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a 8G laptop.The installation went excellent. After that I installed obs studio and tested. I worked also perfect.

Then I started copy files from a network drive to Picture folder. The copy process failed because it only copied the directories and the file's name.
I spend hours to reproduce the problem, but I can figure out the root cause of it.

1. Copy via windows with copy and paste : the same issue
2. Copy via windows Copy to-->select destination : same issue, see only directories and files name
3. Even a copy of 1 file has the same issue.
4. Copy via terminal is also same problem, only directories and the file's name are copied.

Is there some status about this issue?

Comment: I have found the cause of the problem I reported
In my case it was the original files. It turns out that the files on the NAS are corrupt.

Comment: After I deleted the corrupt files and put the original files back on the NAS
I have transferred the entire folder from NAS to the laptop. This time the files were transferred successfully.

So, copying files on the laptop Ubuntu 22.04 destop is just fine.

I was not aware that there were corrupt files on the NAS. I work with the NAS every day. Often I upload and download mp3 and mp4 files and play music and movies. The folder I had a problem with had a problem.
Sorry for the inconvenience.